# What is the format expected by a find(id) request?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My backend replies to `find all` requests:

```
User.find();
```

Like this

```
{ 'users' : [ user1_obj, user2_obj ] }
```

Ember-data is happy about it. Now if I do a simple single object find:

```
User.find('user1');
```

I have tried configuring the backend to return any of the following:

```
user1
{ 'user1' : user1_obj }
{ 'user' : { 'user1' : user1_obj } }
{ 'user' : user1_obj }
```

But none of those are working. What should I return from the backend in reply to `find("obj-id")` requests? According to the documentation about [JSON ROOT](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-root), the right format looks like:

```
{ 'user' : user1_obj }
```

Ember does not complain about it, but the Ember Objects processed have a very strange structure, like this:

[image: object recursion]

As you can see, `_reference.record` is referring to the top record. Also (not shown here) `_data` field is empty.

What could be causing that strange nesting?

### EDIT

As linked by mavilein in his answer, the JSON API suggests using a different [format](http://jsonapi.org/format/) for singular resources:

```
{ 'users' : [user1_obj] }
```

That means, the same format as for plural resources. Not sure if Ember will swallow that, I'll check now.

Answer (score 1):

Following this [specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/), i would suspect the following:

```
{ 
 'users' : [{
   "id": "1",
   "name" : "John Doe"
  },{
    "id": "2",
    "name" : "Jane Doe"
  }]
}
```

For singular resources the specification says:

> Singular resources are represented as JSON objects. However, they are
>   still wrapped inside an array:

```
{ 
 'users' : [{
   "id": "1",
   "name" : "John Doe"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is for a `find all` operation, and that is already working for me. The problem I have is with a `find single object` operation. But thanks for the link to the JSON api. I see there that there is a possible conflict in the format for singular resources: ember documentation says `user`, json api documentation says `users`. I must verify this.

Comment: Yeah it says, that it should be an array in the single find case too.

Comment: This is no longer the case with ember-data 1.0.0b1 and above - the singular resource should not be wrapped in an array, and it should be a singular name.

Answer (score 1):

Using `User.find()` will expect the rootKey pluralized and in your content an array of elements, the response format is the following json:

```
{
  users: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Kris' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Luke' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Formerly Alex' }
  ]
}
```

And with `User.find(1)` the rootKey in singular, and just one object:

```
{
  user: {
    id: 1, name: 'Kris'
  }
}
```

[Here a demo showing this working](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Qtvwa/)

Comment: Nice `mockjax` you have there! Didn't know about that one; it can prove very useful. Question: why `Ember.RSVP.hash` in the index route model, and not directly a js object `{users : blah, user: blah}`?

Comment: Yes, mockjax is awesome. I used the `Ember.RSVP.hash` just to simplify, and not create other route. I am lazy :). You use  `Ember.RSVP.hash` when you want to load more than one model by route. Obviously in a real app, you would map one route per resource ;)